# Shifting the same constant by another yields two different answers?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm debugging some code and came across some behavior I cannot explain.

I am trying to shift the number -1 to the left 32 times to produce a zero in this particular case.

```
int n = 0;
int negOne = ~0;
int negativeN = ( (~n) + 1 );
int toShift = (32 + negativeN);   //32 - n

/*HELP!!! These produce two different answers*/
printf("%d << %d = %d \n",negOne, toShift, negOne << toShift);
printf("-1 << 32 = %d \n", -1 << 32) ;
```

Here is the what the console outputs:

```
-1 << 32 = -1 
-1 << 32 = 0
```

I am not sure why the left shift is behaving differently in each of these cases.

Comment: This is usually a sign of undefined behaviour.

Comment: [Coincidental question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611903/unexpected-behavior-while-dealing-with-shift-operators). Related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you Shift a number equal to or more than the number of its bit times your result can't be predictable! Simply it is [Undefined_behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you compile your program with flags you will get warning for this shifting

Comment: To be precise, this is true for signed integer types, but not for unsigned types; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22883850/2611123

Comment: @ChrisCulter you're looking at the wrong clause; shifting by the width of the type (or more) is undefined for all types.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm afraid I disagree; this sentence seems pretty clear: "If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^(E2), reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type."

Comment: @MattMcNabb Hmm, that section number and that language don't exist in [C99 + TC1 + TC2 + TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards). Are you quoting a C++ standard?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Sorry, C11 (n1570) 6.5.7/3 "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined." Similar (or identical) text is in C99 and C89. It's about an inch above the text you quoted (depending on your screen size)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh! I see, the conditions in that paragraph are meant to apply before the following paragraphs. My mistake, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3):

It's [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you shift count is bigger than the number of bits for an `int`, that means that the result can't be predicted.

Comment: It is also UB because the left operand is signed (see duplicate linked above.)

Comment: bigger than or **equal to**, in this example, they are equal ;)

Comment: To clarify juanchopanza's point, if the left operand were unsigned, the result *would* be defined. The behavior is undefined only when the left operand is signed and the arithmetic value of the shift is not representable. For details see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22883850/2611123

Comment: @ChrisCulter it would still be undefined if the left operand were unsigned.