# how to make a 3D mask

Tags: c

Currently I meet one technique issue, which makes me want to improve the previous implementation, the situation is:

I have 5 GPIO pins, I need use these pins as the hardware identifier, for example:

```
pin1: LOW
pin2: LOW
pin3: LOW
pin4: LOW
pin5: LOW
```

this means one of my HW variants, so we can have many combinations. In previous design, the developer use `if-else` to implement this, just like:

```
if(PIN1 == LOW && ... && ......&& PIN5 ==LOW) 
{
    HWID = variant1;
}
else if( ... )
{
}
...
else
{
}
```

but I think this is not good because it will have more than 200 variants, and the code will become to long, and I want changed it to a mask. The idea is I treat this five pins as a five bits register, and because I can predict which variant I need to assign according to GPIOs status(this already defined by hardware team, they provide a variant list, with all these GPIO pins configuration), therefore, the code may look like this:

```
enum{
    variant 0x0    //GPIO config 1
    ...
    variant 0xF3   //GPIO config 243
}
```

then I can first read these five GPIO pins status, and compare to some mask to see if they are equal or not.

**Question**

However, for GPIO, it has three status, namely: LOW, HIGH, OPEN. If there is any good calculation method to have a 3-D mask?

Comment: What do the constants `LOW`, `HIGH`, and `OPEN` correspond to?

Comment: As I understand you will have 125 combinations (5L*5H*5O) or I am losing something?

Comment: @CrApHeR nope, it'll be pow(3,5) = 243 combinations.

Comment: @CrApHeR, it should be 3^5, because I have 5 GPIO pins, and each pin has three status

Comment: Ups... @kibibu you are right, I think I have to go to sleep :D

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline, in previous, `LOW` means `0` and `HIGH` means `1`, but now, this has `OPEN` status, I don't know what value should I assign to it for mask implementation

Comment: @HowChen I post an answer with a compilable code.  If you want to try it... It is compilable and working.   BTW, It had a very looong day, 3^5 is 243 you and kikibu are right and sorry is the explanation is not the best, english is not my first language. :P

Comment: @CrApHeR, already got it, same with you, i didn't sleep last night and try to figure out this issue:(

Comment: It is a nice challenge.... I like this kind of challenges and I love to program in C... :P

Comment: Well, the value `OPEN` is defined somewhere, isn't it? By definition, a bit can only have one of two values: 0 and 1. Therefore each GPIO pin can only have one of these two values. So how is this extra state implemented?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline, my idea is to first read the GPIO status, for `LOW` and `HIGH` it easy, for `OPEN`, I will use internal `pull-up` and `pull-down` resistors to test this pin if it open or not, then maybe I can assign a new value to `OPEN`, means I will have a separated private table for my GPIO detection?

Comment: IMO: this is a very bad hardware design if the GPIO pins are not pulled (for instance) low and have a pullup resistor to + when designating a 1 bit.  therefore, there are only 2^5 valid possibilities.  Now, the powerup/testing/BIT for those GPIO pins should be checking for an open condition and flagging that as an invalid value.

Comment: @user3629249, for `LOW` and `HIGH`, we do have the resistor outside to pull it to ground or vcc, for `OPEN`, I only can use internal resistor to test each status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 5 pins of 3 states each. You can approach representing this in a few ways.

First, imagine using this sort of framework:

```
#define LOW (0)
#define HIGH (1)
#define OPEN (2)

uint16_t config = PIN_CONFIG(pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4, pin5);

if(config == PIN_CONFIG(LOW, HIGH, OPEN, LOW, LOW))
{
    // do something
}

switch(config) {
    case PIN_CONFIG(LOW, HIGH, OPEN, LOW, HIGH):
        // do something;
        break;
}

uint16_t config_max = PIN_CONFIG(OPEN, OPEN, OPEN, OPEN, OPEN);
uint32_t hardware_ids[config_max + 1] = {0};

// init your hardware ids
hardware_ids[PIN_CONFIG(LOW, HIGH, HIGH, LOW, LOW)] = 0xF315;
hardware_ids[PIN_CONFIG(LOW, LOW, HIGH, LOW, LOW)] = 0xF225;

// look up a HWID
uint32_t hwid = hardware_ids[config];
```

This code is just the sort of stuff you'd like to do with pin configurations. The only bit left to implement is `PIN_CONFIG`

---

## Approach 1

The first approach is to keep using it as a bitfield, but instead of 1 bit per pin you use 2 bits to represent each pin state. I think this is the cleanest, even though you're "wasting" half a bit for each pin.

```
#define PIN_CLAMP(x) ((x) & 0x03)
#define PIN_CONFIG(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)  \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p1) &                      \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p2) << 2) &                \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p3) << 4) &                \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p4) << 6) &                \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p5) << 8))
```

This is kind of nice because it leaves room for a "Don't care" or "Invalid" value if you are going to do searches later.

---

## Approach 2

Alternatively, you can use arithmetic to do it, making sure you use the minimum amount of bits necessary. That is, ~1.5 bits to encode 3 values. As expected, this goes from 0 up to 242 for a total of 3^5=243 states.
Without knowing anything else about your situation I believe this is the smallest complete encoding of your pin states.
(Practically, you have to use 8 bits to encode 243 values, so it's higher 1.5 bits per pin)

```
#define PIN_CLAMP(x) ((x) % 3) /* note this should really assert */
#define PIN_CONFIG(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)  \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p1) &                      \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p2) * 3) &                 \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p3) * 9) &                 \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p4) * 27) &                \\
  (PIN_CLAMP(p5) * 81))
```

---

## Approach 1.1

If you don't like preprocessor stuff, you could use functions a bit like this:

```
enum PinLevel (low = 0, high, open);

void set_pin(uint32_t * config, uint8_t pin_number, enum PinLevel value) {
    int shift = pin_number * 2; // 2 bits
    int mask = 0x03 << shift; // 2 bits set to on, moved to the right spot
    *config &= ~pinmask;
    *config |= (((int)value) << shift) & pinmask;
}

enum PinLevel get_pin(uint32_t config, uint8_t pin_number) {
    int shift = pin_number * 2; // 2 bits
    return (enum PinLevel)((config >> shift) & 0x03);
}
```

*This follows the first (2 bit per value) approach.*

---

## Approach 1.2

YET ANOTHER WAY using C's cool bitfield syntax:

```
struct pins {
    uint16_t pin1 : 2;
    uint16_t pin2 : 2;
    uint16_t pin3 : 2;
    uint16_t pin4 : 2;
    uint16_t pin5 : 2;
};

typedef union pinconfig_ {
    struct pins pins;
    uint16_t value;
} pinconfig;

pinconfig input;
input.value = 0; // don't forget to init the members unless static

input.pins.pin1 = HIGH;
input.pins.pin2 = LOW;

printf("%d", input.value);

input.value = 0x0003;
printd("%d", input.pins.pin1);
```

The union lets you view the bitfield as a number and vice versa.

(note: all code completely untested)

Comment: i don't want to use `bit field`(for further porting issues) and i also don't want to use to many `if-else` condition

Comment: @HowChen Kikibu gave you a very good explanation with more alternatives. I was thinking during the night and another way I though was the 2nd one from kikibu post (using 8 bits instead of 10 bits).  With that example you can have the enum you want. Maybe we don't understand your requirements, can you add more information about them in your post?

Comment: @HowChen What porting issues do you anticipate? At some point you want to discover whether you pin is in one of the 3 states, this answer presumes you have already done that and encoded it as 0, 1 or 2.
.
Regarding if-else, I'll add some example stuff

Comment: @kibibu, for porting issue, because we have different vendor, so in general, our code check and review rule will not allow `bit field`, for this case, seems OK, but if consider a real register case, base on different architecture, `bit filed` may cause some problem during porting between different platform, but I really appreciate your answer

Comment: As long as you're not loading and saving these bitfields to files in weird orders, it should be completely portable to use bitmasks and bitwise operations, even if C bitfields (like approach 1.2) are out. 0x01 << 8 is 256 on every sane architecture. What is not portable is signed negative integer shifts. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883790/left-shift-of-negative-values

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion to solve the problem

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define LOW 0
#define HIGH 1
#define OPEN 2

#define MAXGPIO 5

int main()
{
    int gpio[MAXGPIO] = { LOW, LOW, OPEN, HIGH, OPEN };

    int mask = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXGPIO; i++)
        mask = mask << 2 | gpio[i];  

    printf("Masked: %d\n", mask);
    printf("Unmasked:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXGPIO; i++)
        printf("GPIO %d = %d\n", i + 1, (mask >> (2*(MAXGPIO-1-i))) & 0x03); 

    return 0;
}
```

A little explanation about the code.

**Masking**
I am using 2 bits to save each GPIO value. The combinations are:

- `00: LOW`
- `01: HIGH`
- `02: OPEN`
- 03 is Invalid

I am iterating the array gpio (where I have the acquired values) and creating a mask in the `mask` variable shifting left 2 bits and applying an `or` operation.

**Unmasking**
To get the initial values I am just making the opposite operation shifting right 2 bits multiplied by the amount of GPIO - 1 and masking with 0x03

I am applying a mask with **0x03** because those are the bit I am interested.

This is the result of the program

```
$ cc -Wall test.c -o test;./test
Masked: 38
Unmasked:
GPIO 1 = 0
GPIO 2 = 0
GPIO 3 = 2
GPIO 4 = 1
GPIO 5 = 2
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This only works if each pin is defined by two bits, which may not be the case.

Comment: Yes, that is true.  You just need 2 bits to save 3 states.